# How to convert db results into 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list

I want to take only two columns from the table and put it not in the list, but into 2D array of strings `string[,]`. Here what I do:

```
string[,] array = _table.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
     .Select(y => new string[,] {{y.Name, y.Street}});
```

And now I don't know how to execute it. If I do `.ToArray()` I'll get `string[][,]`. Anybody knows how to solve it with LINQ, without using a loop?

Comment: You can't get `string[,]` as an output of LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in LINQ that let you create multidimentional array. However, you can create your own extension method which will return `TResult[,]`:

```
public static class Enumerable
{
    public static TResult[,] ToRectangularArray<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult[]> selector)
    {
        // check if source is null
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        // load all items from source and pass it through selector delegate
        var items = source.Select(x => selector(x)).ToArray();

        // check if we have any items to insert into rectangular array
        if (items.Length == 0)
            return new TResult[0, 0];

        // create rectangular array
        var width = items[0].Length;
        var result = new TResult[items.Length, width];
        TResult[] item;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            item = items[i];

            // item has different width then first element
            if (item.Length != width)
                throw new ArgumentException("TResult[] returned by selector has to have the same length for all source collection items.", "selector");

            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                result[i, j] = item[j];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But as you can see, it still gets all result into jagged array `TResult[][]` first, and then use loops to rewrite it into multidimentional array.

Usage example:

```
string[,] array = _table.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
                        .ToRectangularArray(x => new string[] { x.Name, x.Street });
```

Comment: @Sayse I don't know why was this downvoted, but I know `== false` is part of original query from question, and that's why I didn't change that to `!IsDeleted`.

Answer (score 2):

`string[,]` is not possible to get as an output of LINQ query.

As an alternative you can try something like this:-

```
 string[][] array = _table.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).Select(y => new[] {y.Name, y.Streete}).ToArray();
```

OR

```
var array =_table.Select(str=>str.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
        .Select(y => new[] {y.Name, y.Street})
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: He wants `string[,]`, not `string[][]`

Comment: string[,] is a multidimensional array and OP has mentioned to convert it into a 2D array.(Correct me if I am wrong!!)

Comment: He specified that he want's `string[,]`. `string[][]` is jagged array of strings.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:- Just updated my answer. Hope this works!!!! Do correct me if I am completely wrong:)

Comment: @RahulTripathi Still `string[][]`.

Comment: Yes...I am really sorry Sir but I am really not getting your point. OP wants to convert it into a 2D array. And my code works fine for that. Could you please explain me where I am going wrong?

Comment: @RahulTripathi You don't see a difference between `string[,]` and `string[][]`. I think that's the problem here :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:- As you have already mentioned string[,] is not possible. I am trying to give a solution. :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek:- I know the difference between string[,] and string[][] but I think to convert it in string[,] is not possible. :)

Comment: Linq query returns `IEnumerable<T>` string[,] Doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`