# two arrays to one 2D

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays that are same length and type and I would like to combine them into one with same length and 2 rows.

for example:

```
      VolunteeringForWardLogicData[] v1, v2;
```

and I want each of the arrays will be in a row in this matrix:

```
     VolunteeringForWardLogicData[,] arr= new VolunteeringForWardLogicData[2, v1.Length];
```

how can i do it?
i saw this example
[Combining same length arrays into one 2d array in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243982/combining-same-length-arrays-into-one-2d-array-in-f)

but I did not really understand how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a loop to assign the items from the source lists to your new list:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var list2 = new int[] { 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    
    var combined = new int[2, list1.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
    {
        combined[0, i] = list1[i];
        combined[1, i] = list2[i];
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{combined[0, i]}: {combined[1, i]}");
    }
}
```

Or, you could create an array of arrays (slightly different to your request) by using [Enumerable's Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) function:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var list2 = new int[] { 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    
    var combined = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new int[]{a, b});
    
    foreach (var item in combined) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item[0]}: {item[1]}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1: 11
2: 12
3: 13
4: 14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spans, it will be much faster than for loops:

```
static T[,] CombineArrays<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2)
{
    if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("arrays must have the same length");

    var ret = new T[2, array1.Length];

    Span<T>
        row1 = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref ret[0, 0], array1.Length),
        row2 = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref ret[1, 0], array2.Length);

    array1.CopyTo(row1);
    array2.CopyTo(row2);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
Do I need to add anything to use MemoryMarshal and Span?

Comment: @N.A You won't have them only if you are using an old version of C# / .Net. They've been in the standard library for a few years. `MemoryMarshal` is in `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Comment: in order to use Span i added the Nuget Package  System.Memory,But in what command to change the command MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan?

Comment: @N.A You are probably using some old .Net version if you needed to add a Nuget package. If you don't have `Span`s and `MemoryMarshal` available out of the box, stick to `for` loops for or `Zip` 2d arrays